# node is giving garbage value

Tags: c, xcode3.2

i am doing c program of binary tree while inserting the node to tree after 2 or 3 nodes the child node having garbage value and crashing i am doing in xcode any idea...

```
Bnode createTreeNode()
{
    Bnode node=(Bnode)malloc(sizeof(Bnode));
    return node;    
}

Bnode addTreeNode(Bnode inNode, char *inData)
{
    int compareValue;

    if (inNode == NULL)     
    {
        inNode = createTreeNode();

        inNode->leftNode=NULL;            
        inNode->rightNode=NULL;

        stpcpy(inNode->data,inData);        
    }
    else if((compareValue=strcmp(inData,inNode->data))==0)       
    {        
        inNode->count=inNode->count+1;

    }
    else if(compareValue>1)        
    {        
        inNode->rightNode=addTreeNode(inNode->rightNode,inData);    
    }
    else        
    {            
        inNode->leftNode = addTreeNode(inNode->leftNode,inData);        
    }

    return inNode;    
}
```

this is how i creating node and inserting it to tree.

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: The error is on line 42.

Comment: @Jerry: Your editor must be messed up. Mine's showing the erroneous line being #24! nAre you even looking at the same code?!

Comment: @sbi:  You have your monitor plugged in backwards.

Comment: @sbi: the problem is clearly on your side. **The** answer is 42.

Comment: @James: That would then be an error of Dell, when they assembled this laptop. `<turns it bottom-up>` Hmm. Interesting. It says "edaM ni dnalerI" underneath, suspiciously followed by some Chinese symbols.

Comment: @Jerry: We were in search of __The Error__, not __The Answer__.

Comment: @sbi:oops, silly me. Apparently the OP isn't really after either one though -- he seems to have done nothing to improve the question...

Answer (score 2):

```
Bnode node=(Bnode)malloc(sizeof(Bnode)); //[1]
    return node;
```

> *Argument of malloc is the size of the dynamic memory to be allocated.*

You have provided **size of the pointer to the struct** as the argument instead of **size of the struct** itself.
As a result, less memory is allocated to `Bnode` and eventually you are bound to get garbage values and segmentation faults.

---

Change it to something like

```
Bnode node = malloc(sizeof(struct _bnode));
//where Bnode is pointer to struct _bnode
```

---

*P.S.: [1] Explicit casts (Bnode) not required in C.*

Answer (score 1):

You declared a pointer for your node, but you didn't actually allocate any storage for it, so you have a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). You need to call `malloc()` (or `calloc()`) for each new node, in order to allocate storage.

Comment: Damn, you're good. Ok, how about this. I have this program that's supposed to do this thing, but it crashes. Can you help?

Comment: @RarrRarrRarr: sure - I see where you went wrong - change `if (x = 0)` to `if (x == 0)` - that should fix it. `;-)`